# how to call a function only in specific pages and exclude it from other pages

Tags: functions, page-specific-settings

I have the below functions

```
require_once(GABFIRE_FUNCTIONS_PATH. '/review-options.php');
require_once(GABFIRE_FUNCTIONS_PATH . '/custom.php');
require_once(GABFIRE_FUNCTIONS_PATH . '/shortcodes.php');
require_once(GABFIRE_FUNCTIONS_PATH . '/post-types.php');
```

i want them to be called only on specific page or exclude from specific pages.

### I'm confused on how to do this in function.php please help!

the functions i showed above, does conflict with Q&A plugin. this takes place in qa pages. once i try to answer a question, the answer doesn't appear.answers appears only if i remove those functions. Thus I'm looking for a way how I can disable calling those function in qa_pages

Comment: Post types should be loaded globally. This will create havoc somewhere I'm sure of it.

Answer (score 1):

if you know which page **id** , for example , you can change your page.php

```
if ( get_the_ID() == '99' ) {
       my_specific_page_99_calls();
}
```

and then on functions.php

```
my_specific_page_99_calls(
     require_once(GABFIRE_FUNCTIONS_PATH. '/review-options.php');
     require_once(GABFIRE_FUNCTIONS_PATH . '/custom.php');
     require_once(GABFIRE_FUNCTIONS_PATH . '/shortcodes.php');
     require_once(GABFIRE_FUNCTIONS_PATH . '/post-types.php');
)
```

i'm sure there's other options, but this will get you there.

to exclude from specific pages

```
if ( !in_category('cake') {
       my_specific_page_99_calls();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. The page i want to exclude, is 'aq_page'(by Q&A PLUGIN by wpmudev.). the above functions are called in function.php. I tried your idea but it didn't work.

Comment: does your aq_page have the same template as the others?

Comment: IT HAS DIFFERENT PAGE TEMPLATE

Comment: well then, instead of changing page.php, did you change that page template? also, why the caps?

Comment: actually i should describe the problem clearly, the functions i showed above, does conflict with Q&A plugin. this takes place in qa pages. once i try to answer a question, the answer doesn't appear.answers appears only if i remove those functions. Thus I'm looking for a way how I can disable calling those function in qa_pages.

Comment: i see, functions.php is always requested by wp so if you have those functions not nested in a another function, they will always be called. like i say on my first response, if you nested them, did you get the correct behaviour from the qa_pages? it will break all the other pages that need those files.

Comment: yeh that is true i tried to nest them and the page was broken. so is there a way to get around this problem

Comment: @heradius could you clarify which kind of page was broken? was the qa_pages still broken or did the normal pages broke down?

Comment: the qa_page is broken once i use condition statement not to load in qa_pages and load in other pages.